# Can I run 2 or 3 touch screen monitors on my computer

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

Does anyone know if I can run 2 or 3 touch screens 
on my Windows 7 machine?

I know I would have to plug in 3 USB cables but would they work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , only the touch drivers need to support multi monitor
it will also depend on the touch technology used , best idea is not to mix , stay whit the same brand/ technology